# Additional bibliography in alphabetical order with sorting=none

Tags: biblatex, sorting

My current working example (due to "moewe") is like below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage     [left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage     {titlesec}
\titleformat    {\chapter}[hang]{\raggedright\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{chapter}.\space\space}{0pt}{}{}
\titlespacing*  {\chapter}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}


\usepackage[backend=biber,language=english, style=numeric,sorting=none, ,citestyle=numeric,giveninits=true,dashed=false,bibstyle=authoryear,
refsegment=chapter,backref=true]{biblatex}

\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff

\DeclareSortingTemplate{none}{
  \sort{\field{presort}}
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{\intciteorder}
}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=aa]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=bb]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=cc]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue=dd]
    }
  }
}
\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}                         
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given}                         
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}


\defbibheading{subsubbibintoc}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}} 
\defbibheading{subsubbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}  

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage     {silence}
\WarningFilter  {latex}{Empty bibliography}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
dolor \autocite{moraux}
sit \autocite{knuth:ct:c}~\autocite{spiegelberg}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Second chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{vizedom:related}
ipsum~\cite{gerhardt}
dolor~\cite{augustine}
sit~\cite{ctan}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Third chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{wassenberg},
ipsum~\cite{baez/online}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\printbibheading[title=Global Bibliography,heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Conferences}]

\printbibliography[title=Global Bibliography ALFABETIC ORDER (additionally),heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

I have the Global Bibliography at the end with citation in order but numbered from 1-11 divided on books, articles and eg. Conferences. It is OK.

I need an **extra** Global Bibliography at the end, but in alphabetical order where the numbers refer to this before (I am aware they will be unsorted). Now I have citation orders connected together without division on book etc.

[image]

I don't want changing the sort option because `sorting=none` must remain. I just need additional displaying in alphabetical order in case of faster find appropriate surname, adequate number and page of citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a different sorting we need to start a new `refcontext` with the relevant `sorting` option. But since we want to retain the numeric labels we need to save the previous `refcontext` and restore it for the label numbers.

Note that I changed the solution to [BibLaTeX and number of the Global Bibliography sort from [1] to [36] with refsegment=chapter and sorting=none options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661836/35864) from using `presort` to using the field `usera`. `presort` would also change the sort order of the other sorting schemes, which is not what we want.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  citestyle=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  dashed=false,
  refsegment=chapter,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff

\DeclareSortingTemplate{none}{
  \sort{\field{usera}}
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{\intciteorder}
}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=aa]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=bb]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=cc]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=dd]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}                         
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given}                         
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}


\defbibheading{subsubbibintoc}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}} 
\defbibheading{subsubbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}  

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Empty bibliography}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
dolor \autocite{moraux}
sit \autocite{knuth:ct:c}~\autocite{spiegelberg}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Second chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{vizedom:related}
ipsum~\cite{gerhardt}
dolor~\cite{augustine}
sit~\cite{ctan}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Third chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{wassenberg},
ipsum~\cite{baez/online}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\printbibheading[title=Global Bibliography,heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Conferences}]

\csletcs{saved@blx@refcontext@context}{blx@refcontext@context}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\makeatletter
\AtNextBibliography{%
  \def\blx@setdefaultrefcontext#1{}%
  \csletcs{blx@refcontext@context}{saved@blx@refcontext@context}}
\makeatother
\printbibliography[title=Global Bibliography (alphabetic),heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

[image: Global bibliography: sorted alphabetically, numbering discontinuous]

*edit* Updated in light of [\begingroup \endgroup changing citation numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663613/35864).