# \begingroup \endgroup changing citation numbers

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Thanks "moewe I have solution like below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage     [left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage     {titlesec}
\titleformat    {\chapter}[hang]{\raggedright\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{chapter}.\space\space}{0pt}{}{}
\titlespacing*  {\chapter}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}


\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  citestyle=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  dashed=false,
  refsegment=chapter,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff

\DeclareSortingTemplate{none}{
  \sort{\field{usera}}
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{\intciteorder}
}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=aa]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=bb]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=cc]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=dd]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}                         
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given}                         
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}


\defbibheading{subsubbibintoc}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}} 
\defbibheading{subsubbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}  

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Empty bibliography}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
dolor \autocite{moraux}
sit \autocite{knuth:ct:c}~\autocite{spiegelberg}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Second chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{vizedom:related}
ipsum~\cite{gerhardt}
dolor~\cite{augustine}
sit~\cite{ctan}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Third chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{wassenberg},
ipsum~\cite{baez/online}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\printbibheading[title=Global Bibliography,heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Conferences}]

\csletcs{saved@blx@refcontext@context}{blx@refcontext@context}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\preto\blx@thelabelnumber{%
  \global\csletcs{blx@refcontext@context}{saved@blx@refcontext@context}}
\makeatother
\printbibliography[title=Global Bibliography (alphabetic),heading=bibintoc]
\endgroup

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\begingroup
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addperiod}
\printbibliography[title={Global Bibliography (alphabetic \& continuous numbering)},heading=bibintoc]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

With **\begingroup \endgroup** I have Global bibliography (alphabetic & continuous numbering) and this is OK.

[image]

but for example **in the text**  position `[6]` of the bibliography has now number `[8]` from the last Global Bibliography (alphabetic & continuous numbering). It changes all citation in the text. This should stay `[6]` etc.

[image]

[image]

When I coment **\begingroup \endgroup**

[image]

the citations are correct

[image]

but **continuous numbering**  is broken :(.

[image]

I need in the Global Bibliography (alphabetic & continuous numbering) just only nubers `[1], [2] [3]...[11]` **not conected** with the text and the previous citation numbers `[6] [1]` which should stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following streamlined version that keeps into account that the last bibliography normally sets the default refcontext (which we don't want here).

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  citestyle=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  dashed=false,
  refsegment=chapter,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff

\DeclareSortingTemplate{none}{
  \sort{\field{usera}}
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{\intciteorder}
}


\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=aa]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=bb]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=cc]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=usera, fieldvalue=dd]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}                         
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given}                         
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}


\defbibheading{subsubbibintoc}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}} 
\defbibheading{subsubbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}  

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
dolor \autocite{moraux}
sit \autocite{knuth:ct:c}~\autocite{spiegelberg}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Second chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{vizedom:related}
ipsum~\cite{gerhardt}
dolor~\cite{augustine}
sit~\cite{ctan}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\vspace{5mm}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Third chapter}}

Lorem~\cite{wassenberg},
ipsum~\cite{baez/online}.

\printbibheading[title=Chapter bibliography,heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=book,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=article,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=online,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibintoc,title={Conferences}]

\printbibheading[title=Global Bibliography,heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Online}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,heading=subsubbibliography,title={Conferences}]


\csletcs{saved@blx@refcontext@context}{blx@refcontext@context}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\makeatletter
\AtNextBibliography{%
  \def\blx@setdefaultrefcontext#1{}%
  \csletcs{blx@refcontext@context}{saved@blx@refcontext@context}}
\makeatother
\printbibliography[title=Global Bibliography (alphabetic),heading=bibintoc]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\makeatletter
\AtNextBibliography{%
  \def\blx@setdefaultrefcontext#1{}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addperiod}}
\makeatother
\printbibliography[title={Global Bibliography (alphabetic \& continuous numbering)},heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir. It works. Thank you. I put the last problem when I use \ifthen function thera are problems. Of course if you hve time..... **Biblatex - using bolean function**

Comment: Sir. I have solved the last problem using **if \else \fi*** function agains **ifthen** package and evrythongs works fine. Apparently some  bug exist in ifthen package. I am interested in using ifthen package and I wil try to report the problem to the author. I will give an answer solution to my last post myself but if you find aslo answer it would be great. Thank you for all help.